# Override execute() in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm looking for a ThreadPoolExecutor that will block when it's task queue is full - the current Java implementation rejects new tasks if the underlying queue is full -

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    /*
     * Proceed in 3 steps:
     *
     * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
     * start a new thread with the given command as its first
     * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
     * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
     * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
     *
     * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
     * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
     * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
     * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
     * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
     * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
     *
     * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
     * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
     * and so reject the task.
     */
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}
```

would changing this line:

```
 if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
```

TO

```
 if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.put(command)) {
```

Do the trick?  Am I missing something?

SOLUTION (might help the next person):

```
public class BlockingThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final Semaphore runLock;

    public BlockingThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, int maxTasks) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        runLock = new Semaphore(maxTasks);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        runLock.acquireUninterruptibly();
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        runLock.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Haven't yet - if there's an obvious deadlock it would be easy, but it's hard to diagnose deadlock just from running a test or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the `ThreadPoolExecutor` state and settings because not all task submissions pass through the `BlockingQueue`.  Usually you just want to change the `RejectedExecutionHandler` of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to the `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy` which will throttle submissions.  If you really want to block on submit then you should use a CompletionService and call the 'take' method when you want to block.  You can also create a subclass and use a `Semaphore` to block the execute method.  See [JDK-6648211 : Need for blocking ThreadPoolExecutor](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6648211) for more information.

Comment: Thanks!  I added a Solution to the question that uses a Semaphore - pretty simple.